# How to keep the memory usage limited in a for loop with robot framework

Tags: robotframework

(1) The test suite with installation & running instructions:
https://github.com/TeddyTeddy/robot-fw-rest-instance-library-tests-v2

(2) The test suite is testing a locally running JSON RESTFUL API server:
https://github.com/typicode/json-server

The DB file for the server (i.e. db.json) is at the root of (1). The server reads the file and creates the API endpoints based on it.
An example run of the server:

```
    (base) ~/Python/Robot/robot-fw-rest-instance-library-tests-v2$ json-server --watch db.json

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3000/posts
  http://localhost:3000/comments
  http://localhost:3000/albums
  http://localhost:3000/photos
  http://localhost:3000/users
  http://localhost:3000/todos
```

(3) With the given db.json, you can make the following request to the server:

> GET /posts?_start=<start_index>&_end=<end_index>

where _start is inclusive and _end is exclusive. Note that start_index starts from 0 just like in Array.Slice method.

(4) To be able to comprehensively test (3), i wrote the following Robot Test Case, which is provided in (1):

```
Slicing Posts With All Possible Start And End Combinations
[Documentation]     Referring to the API documentation:
...                 GET /posts?_start=20&_end=30
...                 where _start is inclusive and _end is exclusive
...                 This test case make the above API call with all possible combinations of _start and _end values.
...                 For each call, the test case fetches expected_posts from database for the same _start and _end.
...                 It then compares the expected_posts with observed_posts. It also calculates the expected length
...                 of observed_posts and compares that with the observed length of observed_posts
[Tags]  read-tested     slicing     run-me-only

FOR  ${start_index}     IN RANGE        ${0}    ${NUMBER_OF_POSTS+10}
    FOR  ${end_index}   IN RANGE        ${start_index+1}    ${NUMBER_OF_POSTS + 10 +1}
        Log To Console  start_index:${start_index}
        Log To Console  end_index:${end_index}
        # note that start_index starts from zero when posts are fetched from database
        ${expected_posts} =     Fetch Posts From Database   ${start_index}      ${end_index}
        # note that start_index starts from 0 too when posts are fetched via API call
        # test call
        ${observed_posts} =     Get Sliced Posts    ${start_index}      ${end_index}
        Should Be Equal         ${expected_posts}       ${observed_posts}
        # note that start_index is between [0, NUMBER_OF_POSTS-1]
        # and end_index is between [start_index+1, start_index+NUMBER_OF_POSTS]
        # we expect observed_posts to be a non-empty list at least containing 1 item
        ${observed_length} =            Get Length              ${observed_posts}
        # calculate expected_length of the observed_posts list
        IF  ${end_index} < ${NUMBER_OF_POSTS}
            ${expected_length} =    Evaluate    $end_index-$start_index
        ELSE IF ${end_index} >= ${NUMBER_OF_POSTS} and ${start_index} < ${NUMBER_OF_POSTS}
            ${expected_length} =    Evaluate    $NUMBER_OF_POSTS-$start_index
        ELSE
            ${expected_length} =    Set Variable    ${0}
        END
        Should Be Equal     ${expected_length}      ${observed_length}

        Free Memory     ${expected_posts}       # (*)
        Free Memory     ${observed_posts}       # (*)
    END
    Reload Library      REST     # (**)
END
```

Note that when you follow the instruction to run the test suite via ./run, you will only execute this test case (because of --include run-me-only tag in run command).

**The problem**
As the test case runs, the amount of memory Robot & RESTInstance use grows to gigabyte levels in a few minutes.

**The Question**
How can I prevent this from happening?
How can I free the memory used in inner loop's iteration?

**My failed attempts to fix the problem**
I added the codes marked with (*) into the test case with the following custom keyword:

```
@keyword
def free_memory(reference):
    del reference
```

Note also that I use RESTInstance library to make the GET call:

```
Get Sliced Posts
    [Documentation]     start_index starts from 1 as we fetch from the API now
    [Arguments]         ${start_index}      ${end_index}
    GET     /posts?_start=${start_index}&_end=${end_index}
    ${posts} =  Output      response body
    [Return]    ${posts}
```

AFAIK, RESTInstance library keeps a list of instance objects:
https://asyrjasalo.github.io/RESTinstance/#Rest%20Instances

So, this list is growing by adding an instance object per API call. So, I tried:

```
Reload Library REST  # (**)
```

in the test case, once the iteration with the outermost FOR loop ended. I thought the list would be destroyed & re-created as we reload the library, but the memory consumption kept rising still.

Comment: Robot doesn't like cycles under cycles and that is the problem.
Actually I don't get it why you need to make the code as you do.
Why not use a endless FOR (e.g. FOR ${i} in range 99999999) and then use a external variable to control the cycle?
You can exit at any point the FOR with "EXIT FOR LOOP IF ...."
My advice would be to clear those 2 FOR's that don't make much sense.

Comment: @ClaudioBatista Could you kindly give me example code which utilizes a single FOR loop to accomplish what the test case does?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley do you happen to an an answer to this thread?